# The angle between $u$ and $v$ is $30º$, and the vector $w$ of norm $4$ is ortogonal to both $u,v$. Calculate $[u,v,w]$.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

> The angle between the unit vectors $u$ and $v$ is $30º$, and the vector $w$ of norm $4$ is ortogonal to both $u,v$. The basis $(u,v,w)$ is positive, calculate $[u,v,w]$.

I did the following:

- Take an arbitrary vector of norm $1$, for simplicity I took $u=(1,0,0)$.
- Now I need another vector $v$ with norm $1$ and $30$ degrees from $u$. To do it, I solved the following pait of equations:

$$\frac{(1,0,0)\cdot(x,y,z)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}=\frac{\pi}{6} \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}=1$$

- For simplicity, I took this vector from the  $xy$ plane, that means that $z=0$. Then:

$$\frac{(1,0,0)\cdot(x,y,0)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=\frac{\pi}{6} \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \sqrt{x^2+y^2}=1$$

The solutions are:

$$\begin{array}{cc}
 x_1: \frac{\pi }{6} & y_1: -\frac{1}{6} \sqrt{36-\pi ^2} \\
 x_2: \frac{\pi }{6} & y_2: \frac{\sqrt{36-\pi ^2}}{6} \\
\end{array}$$

- Now to get a vector that is perpendicular to $u,v$, I could use the cross product, but for these two vector, it's pretty easy to figure out I can use $w=(0,0,4)$.
- Now to calculate $[u,v,w]$, I used the following determinants:

$$\
\begin{vmatrix}
 0 & 0 & 4 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 \frac{\pi }{6} & -\frac{1}{6} \sqrt{36-\pi ^2} & 0 \\
\end{vmatrix}=-\frac{2}{3} \sqrt{36-\pi ^2} \quad \quad \quad  \begin{vmatrix}
 0 & 0 & 4 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 \frac{\pi }{6} & \frac{\sqrt{36-\pi ^2}}{6} & 0 \\
\end{vmatrix}=\frac{2 \sqrt{36-\pi ^2}}{3}$$

The problem is that the answer of the book is $2$. I assume it's not some sort of computation mistake because I did it entirely via Mathematica.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is here:
$$
\frac{(1,0,0)\cdot(x,y,z)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}=\frac{\pi}{6}
$$
which should be
$$
\frac{(1,0,0)\cdot(x,y,z)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}=\color{red}\cos\frac{\pi}{6} = \frac 12 \sqrt 3 \, ,
$$
and one solution would be
$$
(x,y,z) = (\cos\frac{\pi}{6}, \sin\frac{\pi}{6}, 0)
$$

(But note that the given conditions still hold if $u$ or $v$ are multiplied
by any positive real number, so without any restriction on the norm
of $u$ and $v$ the solution is not unique.)

Answer (score 1):

The area of the parallelogram spanned by $u$ and $v$ is $ \|u\|\|v\|\sin(30)=1/2$ assuming $\|u\|=\|v\|=1$. Hence the determinant of the three vectors equals $4\cdot1/2$ since they are positive orientated.